# Building a regulated power supply AC-to-DC

Tags: power-supply

What components do I need to build a regulated power supply with an input voltage of 220V AC and outputs of 3V, 6V, 9V, 12V? Assuming max. current of 1A in each outputs.

Comment: in simultaneous outputs

Comment: An unregulated power supply, and some regulators.

Comment: This question is *still* to broad to be answered here. Try the resources I recommended when you posted this the first time.

Comment: Or just buy off-the-shelf wall warts that meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** A linear power supply:

- transformer (at least 50 W output at 12 ... 15 V)
- bridge rectifier
- filter capacitor
- fixed voltage regulators (78XX series)
- some 0.1 ... 0.33 uF capacitors
- optional: some rectifier diodes (to protect regulators in case reverse voltage is applied - if you charge batteries with the supply)

**Option 2:** A switched mode power supply. A 50 W transformer is quite big and heavy, and with the current configuration there will be a big energy loss as unwanted heat. A SMPS is the most effective solution, but you shouldn't build it yourself. There are online services that allow you to create almost any configuration and order the required parts.

Comment: Do you have sources for these online services?  I would love to try them out and analyze their design

Comment: @Funkyguy Have a look at http://poweresim.com/ and NXP's http://www.nxp.com/design-portal/TEA1733.html (P.S. I don't know exactly if they allow ordering kits as I never did that from any of them; you end up with a schematic, I guess you can order parts, but you'll have to design and build the PCB)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll check them out.  Maybe review the services

Comment: @BrianSanchez To add what cornelius stated, there are also switched mode power supplies that can take in a single input and make multiple outputs.  While these can be complicated to layout a PCB for, they are available.  Check out Intersil, Linear Technologies, and TI. They are among the many who offer these kinds of power supplies.